# How to (elegantly) create a dynamic map inside a variable?

Tags: terraform, amazon-eks

I have a `list(string)` as a declared variable, and need to create a map out of it inside a module variable. The context is the AWS `eks` module, which contains an input named `eks_managed_node_groups` of type `any`, although internally is is actually a map:

```
  eks_managed_node_groups = {
    node_group_name = {
      name = name
      ...
    }
  }
```

Want I want to achieve is to have a declared variable of type `list(string)`, in my case containing availability zone identifier, e.g. `[ "a", "b", "c" ]`. Out of this, I want to generate a map that contains one entry per value in the variable, so I get three map elements in `eks_managed_node_groups`, like this:

```
  eks_managed_node_groups = {
    node_group_a = {
      name = a
      ...
    }
    node_group_b = {
      name = b
      ...
    }
    node_group_c = {
      name = c
      ...
    }
  }
```

I got this working, but the solution is not really readable:

```
eks_managed_node_groups = zipmap(
    [ for az in var.availability_zones : "nodes_${az}" ],
    [ for az in var.availability_zones : {
      name = "${az}",
      ...
    }]
  )
```

and I would expect there should be a much more elegant way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove the `zipmap` function and simply assign the `nodes_${az}` as the key in a single `for` expression within the `map` constructor. Otherwise this type of substantial data transformation does require the code you utilize in the question:

```
eks_managed_node_groups = {
  for az in var.availability_zones : "nodes_${az}" => {
    name = $az,
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: just beat me to this one, had the same solution. Only additional I would say is you can remove the quotes and variable interpolation on the name key and just write it as `name = az` since its just a var

Comment: Thanks a lot @matthew-schuchard ! Works great and is much more elegant than my "solution". Can you maybe link me to a documentation of the `=>` assignment operator you used? That was my missing part in the beginning, and even after knowing the solution, I could not find a reference for this in the docs.

Comment: @DirkJablonski It is part of the syntax for `for` expression within `map` constructors. It is kind of "inspired" by Python generator expressions. https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for#result-types

Comment: Thank you very much @MatthewSchuchard, I overlooked that part :facepalm: